# Mounting AWS EFS to ECS EC2 Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Hello I'm using Terraform to try and spin up Zookeeper for a development environment and I keep running into the following issue when I spin up the terraform.

> Stopped reason Error response from daemon: create
> ecs-clearstreet-basis-dev-Zookeeper-46-clearstreet-confluent-c2cf998e98d1afd45900:
> VolumeDriver.Create: mounting volume failed: Specified port [2999] is
> unavailable. Try selecting a different port.

I don't have this issue when attaching an EFS to a Fargate container.

Here is the terraform for reference.

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs-zookeeper" {
  family = "${var.project}-Zookeeper"
  container_definitions = templatefile("./task-definitions/zookeeper.tftpl",
    {
      zookeeper_image                  = "${var.zookeeper_image}:${var.zookeeper_image_version}"
      zookeeper_port                   = "${var.zookeeper_port}"
      zookeeper_port_communication     = "${var.zookeeper_port_communication}"
      zookeeper_port_election          = "${var.zookeeper_port_election}"
      zookeeper-servers                = "server.1=${var.project}1.${var.dns_zone}:2888:3888;2181"
      zookeeper-elect-port-retry       = "${var.zookeeper-elect-port-retry}"
      zookeeper_4lw_commands_whitelist = "${var.zookeeper_4lw_commands_whitelist}"
      aws_region                       = "${var.aws_region}"
    }
  )
  task_role_arn = var.ecs-task-role-arn
  network_mode  = "awsvpc"
  volume {
    name      = "resolv"
    host_path = "/etc/docker_resolv.conf"
  }
  volume {
    name = "Client-confluent"
    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = var.efs-fsid
      root_directory          = "/Platform/confluent"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2999
      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = var.efs-confluent-fsap
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs-zookeeper" {
  name                    = "Zookeeper"
  cluster                 = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs.id
  task_definition         = aws_ecs_task_definition.ecs-zookeeper.arn
  enable_ecs_managed_tags = true
  enable_execute_command  = true
  desired_count           = 1
  propagate_tags          = "SERVICE"
  launch_type             = "EC2"
  # only manual task rotation via task stop
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 33
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  network_configuration {
    subnets          = var.vpc_subnets
    security_groups  = [var.ECS-EC2-SG]
    assign_public_ip = false
  }
  service_registries {
    registry_arn = aws_service_discovery_service.discovery_service-zookeeper.arn
  }
  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "spread"
    field = "host"
  }
  ordered_placement_strategy {
    type  = "spread"
    field = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone"
  }
  placement_constraints {
    type       = "memberOf"
    expression = "attribute:program == PLATFORM"
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  # count = var.zookeeper-instance-number
}

resource "aws_service_discovery_service" "discovery_service-zookeeper" {
  name = "${var.project}-zookeeper"

  dns_config {
    namespace_id = aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace.discovery_namespace.id

    dns_records {
      ttl  = 10
      type = "A"
    }

    routing_policy = "MULTIVALUE"
  }

  health_check_custom_config {
    failure_threshold = 1
  }
  # count = var.zookeeper-instance-number
}
```

Here is the Task Definition for reference

```
[
    {
        "name": "zookeeper",
        "image": "${zookeeper_image}",
        "cpu": 256,
        "memory": 512,
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
            {
                "containerPort": ${zookeeper_port},
                "hostPort": ${zookeeper_port}
            },
            {
                "containerPort": ${zookeeper_port_communication},
                "hostPort": ${zookeeper_port_communication}
            },
            {
                "containerPort": ${zookeeper_port_election},
                "hostPort": ${zookeeper_port_election}
            }
        ],
        "environment": [
            {
                "name": "ZOO_SERVERS",
                "value": "${zookeeper-servers}"
            },
            {
                "name": "ZOO_STANDALONE_ENABLED",
                "value": "false"
            },
            {
                "name": "ZOO_ELECT_PORT_RETRY",
                "value": "${zookeeper-elect-port-retry}"
            },
            {
                "name": "ZOO_4LW_COMMANDS_WHITELIST",
                "value": "${zookeeper_4lw_commands_whitelist}"
            }
        ],
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                    "sourceVolume": "resolv",
                    "containerPath": "/etc/resolv.conf"
            }
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-region" : "${aws_region}",
                    "awslogs-group" : "/fargate/client/basis/program-zookeeper",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix" : "program-zookeeper"
                }
            },
        "workingDir": "/var/lib/zookeeper",
        "mountPoints":[{
            "sourceVolume": "client-confluent",
            "containerPath": "/var/lib/zookeeper"
            }]
    }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running more than one container on a single EC2 instance that is mounting that EFS volume? Is there any reason you are specifying the port for the EFS connection instead of allowing ECS to pick an available port automatically?

Comment: port 2999 is used, by default for in-transit encryption. If I swap the port to 3000 or something else I get the same issue. For now there is only one container running on this instance.

Comment: Where are you seeing port `2999` is a default? All the documentation I'm aware of says it is port `2049`. Regardless, I've run into TONS of issues when trying to manually specify this port, and all those issues went away if I leave the port number empty/unassigned.

Answer (score 0):

When omit transit_encryption_port, Amazon EFS mount helper chooses a port using its own port selection strategy.

Simply delete `transit_encryption_port = 2999` in your Terraform code works.

The code posted in Terraform example doc is not guaranteed to work:  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#example-using-efs_volume_configuration

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
  family                = "service"
  container_definitions = file("task-definitions/service.json")

  volume {
    name = "service-storage"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.fs.id
      root_directory          = "/opt/data"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      # transit_encryption_port = 2999 # remove this line of code
      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.test.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```